# Products not showing in frontend

Tags: product, import, programmatically

I am programmatically importing a list of products in Magento 1.8.1.0.

Although the products are enabled they are not showing in the frontend pages (searches, list, ...).

This are my product attributes:
*Grouped Products:

- Status: Enabled
- Visibility: Catalog, Search
- Manage Stock: NO
- They are in the correct categories
- They are in the Main Website

*Simple Products:

- Status: Enabled
- Visibility: Not visible individually
- Manage Stock: NO
- Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart: 1
- Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart: 10000
- The price is set
- They are in the Main Website

By manually disabling and then reenabling a product in the backend, the toggled product shows up. I created a script to disable and reenable all products and it seems to work locally (OSX) but not on my server (openSuse 11.4).

Is there something I can check in my import script to make it work without toggling all the product status?

EDIT: In the import script I am setting the store id and website like this:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId);
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
```

EDIT 2: This is the script that seems to fix the problem (by setting the again the website Ids it work also on the server)

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    foreach($products as $product){
        $product->load();
        echo "Disabling product: ".$product->getSku()."\n";
        $product->setStatus(2);

        $product->save();

        $product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        echo "Enabling product: ".$product->getSku()."\n";
        $product2->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
        $product2->setStatus(1);

        $product2->save();
    }
```

Comment: once do re-index and flush your cache

Comment: does you have multi website or multi store?

Comment: already done from the backend page and it is not working

Comment: I have one Website and 2 stores (1 disabled), however products are Enabled in both of them.
In my import script I am importing the information in the default store (id=0) and then again in the English store for localization purposes.

Comment: got prb when you import product via code then have you set websiteid and store id?

Comment: I edited the question with a couple of lines of my import script.

Comment: I think not working

Answer (score 1):

OP noted that setting the website IDs seems to resolve the issue:

> ```
> $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
>
> foreach($products as $product){
>     $product->load();
>     echo "Disabling product: ".$product->getSku()."\n";
>     $product->setStatus(2);
>
>     $product->save();
>
>     $product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
>     echo "Enabling product: ".$product->getSku()."\n";
>     $product2->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
>     $product2->setStatus(1);
>
>     $product2->save();
> }
> ```